# How to add a local library to a C# web application to debug?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package, visual-studio-debugging

- I have a project which is published as a nuget package(No way to run standalone).
- I'm installing the above said nuget package in other project and consuming it.
- Now I need to debug the installed nuget package. I have the package's code on my local machine.

***Is there a way where I can reference to local source code instead of downloading and installing nuget package for debugging purpose?***

-**I don't want to publish nuget package with symbols**

Comment: I usually create a separate test-project in the first solution for debugging. But it would be so much nicer if it was possible to temporary redirect nuget-references somehow.